# Overfull hbox problem with latex table

Tags: tables, paragraphs

It's the first time I work with latex and I have a problem with tables. I create the table below

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1in}p{1in}}
\toprule
URI&\multicolumn{2}{l}{/RBP/config/startpresenceverification}\\ \midrule
HTTP method&\multicolumn{2}{l}{POST}\\ \midrule
Parameters&presenceverurl&String\\ \cline{2-3}
&presencevermode&String\\ \cline{2-3}
&presencevermessage&String\\ \cline{2-3}
&maxsuspicions&int\\ \cline{2-3}
&suspicionsinterval&long\\ \cline{2-3}
&exemptiontime&long\\ \midrule 
\end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\label{table:test}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Except the first and the fourth parameter, I got four warnings for the other lines:

> \overfull hbox ... in paragraph ...

And this is how the table looks like when I compile the file
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: You defined a tabular with 3 columns (`\begin{tabular}{lp{1in}p{1in}}`), the first one is left aligned and the two others are 1in large paragraphs. 1in is not large enough to contain all your text. Moreover, your text is only one word, that's why the paragraph is only written on one line.

You should try `\begin{tabular}{llp{1in}}` or `\begin{tabular}{lp{3in}p{1in}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third column are to small, to fit long words like "presenceverur" into them.

Is there a need for you, to define the width of the columns yourself?  It would be easier, if you let LaTeX do the job for you.  So you could write

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}}
```

Note, that the @{} suppress the white space on the left and right side of the table.

I'd also suggest, that leave the `\clines` away.  If you insist on them, you should be consistent to the `booktabs`-package and use `\cmidrule` instead.  It will not only have the same width, as the `\midrule`.  It will also add some gap between the line and the cell contents.  But I think, your table does not need those lines at all ...

## Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}}
      \toprule
      URI
      &\multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{/RBP/config/startpresenceverification}\\ 
      \midrule
      HTTP method & \multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{POST}\\ 
      \midrule
      Parameters & presenceverurl & String\\
      & presencevermode & String\\
      & presencevermessage & String\\
      & maxsuspicions & int\\ 
      & suspicionsinterval & long\\
      & exemptiontime & long\\
      \midrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{test}
    \label{table:test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: You (and the OP) should use `\centering`, rather than the `center` environment.